# Source code through JDI

Tags: javascript, java, debugging, nashorn, jdi

I'm tying to programmatically debugging Nashorn engine using Java debug interface. I'm get `jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$1$23A$\^eval\_` stack frame and can view source locations in this frame. But I want to load executing JavaScript source code and don't know how to do this (There is wasn't JS files, code were loaded in engine by direct `eval` call). I know that NetBeans can debugging JavaScript and extracting JS code from Nashorn. What magic it uses?

Comment: When you debug using JDI the class jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.DebuggerSupport can be used to obtain script-related information, e.g. source info including content, value info and proper "object-as-string" representations. The notifyInvoke can also be used as a breakpoint for function invocations. I haven't had a chance to try myself, but assume that NetBeans uses this internally.

Comment: Hi Alex Faust: this approach will not work with jdk9. Nashorn module's jdk.nashorn.internal.* packages are concealed packages.